# Facebook Graph API : detect action of feeds in /feed

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I now developing an app that working with **Facebook Graph API**
Graph providing **/me/feed** end-point to retrieve all feeds of authorized user.
The issue here is how to detect action of feeds, such as : added photo, updated status...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result of the end-point : **me/feed**, each feed provide a field named : **status_type**. So, base on this field, you can detect the action of feed.For example : **added_photos, shared_story, app_created_story, tagged_in_photo**